# Table and sub-query are not joined ? Nested queries (only select and SUM)

Tags: infinidb

I have 1 table and I tried this query with InfiniDB :

```
SELECT sum(montantTTC) FROM ticket
WHERE year(creation_iso) IN (SELECT distinct year(creation_iso) as annee 
                             FROM ticket ORDER BY annee);
```

But I have an error : `Erreur SQL (138): IDB-1000: 'ticket' and 'sub-query' are not joined.`

Why ? I don't understand...

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want the sum per year?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Sum of each year ( and afterwards, sum each month each year )

Comment: I can do that : `SELECT month(creation_iso), year(creation_iso), round(sum(montantTTC)) FROM ticket
GROUP BY month(creation_iso), year(creation_iso)
ORDER BY year(creation_iso), month(creation_iso);`

But I would like to know why nested queries doesn't work.

Comment: Can you perhaps set up an SQLFiddle for InfiniDB? I tested this on SQL Server and it did not throw error.

Comment: Yes, also on mysql... I don't know SQLFiddle but I'm going to see it =)